# Find why mysqld is trying to reach a blacklisted IP

Tags: mysql

On a server of mine, its local ESET firewall is blocking MariaDB's mysql process from accessing a blacklisted IP `154.12.54.163:1277`. MariaDB is installed and expected on the server.

I've also tried `netstat -a -o -p TCP` but that doesn't show me anything connected to that IP (which makes sense because the firewall didn't allow it). But I'm wondering if anything I find is going to point to mysql, which I know but what I don't know is what is trying to use mysql.

This is what I'm getting from the Eset log:

```
Object
{Internal IP} ->154.12.54.163:1277
Process
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.0\bin\mysqld.exe
```

Comment: That IP is associated with HostHub. Does your server need a connection to that service?

Comment: @schroeder MariaDB is a normal part of the server yes. Connections are also trying to be made to 92.255.78.144 and blocked. No idea waht is hostHub or why I would be trying to connect to it. I googled those IP and they are showing up on a list of blocked IPs

Comment: @schroeder But nothing should be trying to connect to any "HostHub" at least I need to know what is trying to do that.

Comment: Why would the MySQL Server be establishing connections to other destinations? I have not encountered such a use case before. I am accustomed to a client connecting to the MySQL server and running a query. Thus the MySQL connections are only Ingress.

Comment: @StevenK7FAQ I really don't know. Do you know what I can probably check ? or where I can look for the IP?

Comment: @unknowntechh - The only use case that comes to mind that a DB Server would try to connect to another reource would be to connect to another MySQL instance for replication.